# Передвижение коллекции "по кругу"

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции

Представим, что есть коллекция целочисельных значений.
Например, `1 5 8 3 0 15 7`. Есть какой-то метод, который бы передвигал значения на какое-то определенно число?
Например, хочу передвинуть все значения на 2 влево. Тогда она будет иметь такой вид `8 3 0 15 7 1 5`.

Comment: Для таких вещей fifo очередь прекрасно подходит

Comment: @yolosora точно, спасибо! Напишите это как ответ, я поставлю вам плюс.

Comment: При определённых видах применения может быть шустрее контейнер на базе массива длины `n` с числом-смещением `d`. Чтобы чтение `i`-го элемента возвращало `(i+d)%n`'ый элемент массива. Смещение на 2 влево будет выражаться всего лишь в уменьшении `d` на 2 (можно ещё брать остаток от деления на `n` у результата, чтобы избежать спецэффектов от больших `d`).

Comment: для коллекций есть стандартный метод [`java.utils.Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-). Для массивов примитивов вроде нет, можно почитать про возможные реализации [здесь](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выше написал yolosora, для такой цели подойдет fifo.